# validate the path in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I validate a folder path in javascript?

For example, if I enter the path:

```
 c:\myfolder\hi\
```

it must be validated to some expression saying user must input the path as:

```
c:\\myfolder\\hi\\
```

Users may specify a path of any length.

Comment: path must contain double backslash.. \\

Comment: Why should you put such a constraint on user? Convert single backslash to double before using it. User should not be aware of underlying process.

Comment: JavaScript is mostly commonly seen on the WWW — why are you constraining the file path to a style used on a specific OS? Or worrying about file paths in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Regular_Expressions):

```
if (user_given_string.match(/^[a-z]:(\\\\([a-z]+))*\\\\?$/i)) { OK } else { wrong }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(path.match(/^[a-z]+\\/|\\){1,2}([^\/\\\<\>\:\"\?\|\*]+(\/|\\))*[^\/\\\<\>\:\"\?\|\*]+\.[a-z]+$/i)) 
{
   true;
}
else 
{
   false;
}
```